# How to find PC from list of users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need some help. I'm not so sure that this possible.

I have list of `samAccountName` in `.csv` file, and from this I need to get their PC name and IP.

I'm not so sure how to build script like this.

Comment: There's no 1:1 association of a user and a computer object in Active Directory - this is impossible to do.

Comment: You'll need to analyze the audit logs from your Domain Controllers is you want to know where people log in :)

Comment: you would need to associate the two ... and it is not done by default in AD. [*grin*] some companies have a login script that puts the user name in the computer object description. others have the computer name put into the _user object_ description. however, none of that is built in. you can either do as `Mathias R. Jessen` mentioned, OR scan each system to get the last logged in user, OR see if the `.PrimaryOwnerName` or `.UserName` properties of the `CIM_ComputerSystem` class for each system has that info set.

Comment: Maybe you can get all AD computers, do a wmi query and get the all users, then filter your wanted users from the list to know which is their computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this could be to loop through all computers in your environment and test each one. This of course will be **SLOW**

There is no example of what your CSV file looks like in the question, but if it looks something like this:

```
    "SamAccountName","title"
    "jdoe","testuser"
    "rboizov","system administrator"
```

You can do:

```
# get an aray if SamAccountNames from the Csv
$userNames = Import-Csv -Path 'PathToYOurCsvFile' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

# get all computer objects from AD and loop through
# this of course can take a LONG time to finish..
$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Testing computer $($_.Name)"
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $pc = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
        # or use: $pc = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name

        $user = ($pc.UserName -split '\\')[-1]
        if ($userNames -contains $user) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                'SamAccountName' = $user
                'ComputerName'   = $pc.Name
                'IP'             = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc.Name -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $($_.Name) could not be reached"
    }
}

#output in console
$result

# output to Csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'UsersOnComputers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>There might be a faster way, but that can only work if all home directories of your users have been redirected to a central server\share. If that is the case in your environment, let me know</sup>

---

*Experimental*

The below method uses `Win32_ServerConnection` to find all sessions to user HomeDrive folders.

**This can only work if all home directories of your users have been redirected to a central `\\server\share`, and of course if your permissions allow it**

```
 # the UNC \\Server\Share name of the network share where all user homedirectories are
$usersHomePath = '\\HomesServer\HomesShare$' 

# get an aray if SamAccountNames from the Csv
$userNames = Import-Csv -Path 'PathToYOurCsvFile' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

# split the UNC path to get the server name and share name separate
$svr = $usersHomePath.TrimStart("\") -split '\\'        #"# fix syntax highlighting for SO..
$server = $svr[0]
$share  = $svr[-1]

$result = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName $server |  # or use: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ServerConnection
            Where-Object { $_.ShareName -eq $share -and $userNames -contains $_.UserName } |
            Select-Object @{Name = "SamAccountName"; Expression = { $_.UserName }}, 
                          @{Name = "ComputerName"; Expression = {(([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_.ComputerName).HostName) -split "\.")[0]}},
                          @{Name = "IP"; Expression = { (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString }} |
            Sort-Object SamAccountName

#output in console
$result

# output to Csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'UsersOnComputers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```